# How to increment variable value from 0x00 to 0x11 (in hex)

Tags: bash, hex

Can anyone tell how to increment variable value by one from 0x00 to 0x04 in the bash.
I want to generate:

```
0x00
0x01
0x02
0x03
0x04
```

But I am getting the following result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

My code is :

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( num=0x0; num <= 0x04 ; num+=1 ));
do 
    echo $num
done
```

Comment: Why are you saying "memory location"? It's just a bash variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` to print the number as hex:

```
for (( num=0x0; num <= 0x20 ; num+=1 )); do 
    printf '0x%02X\n' $num
done
```

Note that `num` is nothing special. Even though you initialize it with `0x0`, it's just 0. Even when we pass `num` to `printf`, it is done so as decimal (so 0x11 is passed as 17). It is `printf` that formats your number as hex.